# array list search with query loads only last intery

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have this codes to search inside the array list, It is searching perfectly to match the user input and it is working fine, the problem is the array list "mNotes" is only bring the last entry , I cannot search the whole array lists that i got , it will show the result only if I put a letter which included in the last entry .

//searchActivity.class//

```js
package com.example.boc.PhoneNumbers;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.boc.R;
import com.example.boc.main.phone_nombers_Activity;
import com.example.boc.models.Note;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class searchActivity extends phone_nombers_Activity {

    private DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
    public TextView resultsTxt , userinput ;

    public FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    public Note note ;
    public LinearLayout layout ;
    private ArrayList<Note> mNotes = new ArrayList<>();

    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.collection("notes").document();
    private CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db.collection("notes");




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_search );

        final EditText userinput = findViewById( R.id.userInputtxt );
        final Button   findbutton = findViewById( R.id.findBtn );
        Button   openresultBtn = findViewById( R.id.openresult );
        final TextView previewResultTextview = findViewById( R.id.resultsTxt );

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        CollectionReference notesCollectionRef = db
                .collection("notes");

        Query notesQuery = null;
        if(documentSnapshot != null){
            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef;

        }
        else{
            notesQuery = notesCollectionRef
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        }

        notesQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
                        Note note = document.toObject(Note.class);
                        mNotes.add(note);

        final String datafromdb = note.getTitle();


        findbutton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String userinputString = userinput.getText().toString();
                if ( datafromdb.contains( userinputString )  ){
                    previewResultTextview.setText( datafromdb );

                }
                else {
                    previewResultTextview.setText("no result found");
                }

            }
        } );







    }}}});


}}
```

Comment: javascript and jQuery, are you sure?

Comment: This is java, not javascript, please fix it

Comment: sorry, didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the entire `mNotes` array using `filter`:

```
Note match = null;

for (Note note : mNotes) {
    if (note.getTitle().contains(userinputString)) {
        match = note;
        break;
    }
}

if (match != null) {
    // Found a match
    previewResultTextview.setText(match.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast replay , got this Cannot resolve method 'contains(?)'

Comment: Try using `getTitle`

Comment: perfect!!!, thanks man, one question here, why it loaded the last entry in my codes?

Comment: Now I have to look for a way to fitch that data so the user can open the entry with that he searched for.

Comment: The original code was setting `setOnClickListener` on each element. You can move that call below the loop instead.

Comment: I will ask another question soon, appreciated if you could take a look, I searched the net for all the day didn't find a clear solution.

Comment: my friend I posted a new problem regarding this one, I would highly appreciate it if you could take a look at it.